# WebPage Is Not Rendered, HTML Source Code Shows Instead

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I need help. I've been spending hours to figure out the root cause but couldn't found. I don't know why my web page rendered perfectly in browsers IE 11.0 and Firefox but not Chrome. When running in Chrome, it will show the HTML source code instead of the webpage itself. I implemented bootstrap version 3.0. Isn't it compatible with Chrome? Does any of you know what is the root cause? Appreciate very much. Below is a part of the source code which shows up in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MiniRentas/style/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MiniRentas/style/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MiniRentas/style/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MiniRentas/style/js/jssha256.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/MiniRentas/style/js/keypress.js"></SCRIPT>
```

I have debugged using developer tools in Chrome and here is the result of response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 02:05:53 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=09026A63010D5638F2E305A481CCEF67; 
Path=/MiniRentas/; Secure; HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure
Content-Length: 2328
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: How exactly are you opening that page?

Comment: Is that the whole html?

Comment: Bootstrap version 3 is compatible with chrome. Can you please post the whole html and also state your chrome version?

Comment: The missing `Content-Type` HTTP header may be throwing Chrome off; adding a `Content-Type: text/html` should trigger proper HTML processing. Perhaps it's also the malformed `Set-Cookie` header; does it really have a line break in the middle…?

Comment: @deceze it is actually a login page.when first load it can render perfectly, but let say if in case I click the Login button without filling username and password, then it shows the HTML source code instead of redirecting to the login page back.(this case happens when no values entered, wrong password, and wrong username).If the login credentials is correct, it will rendered perfectly - taking user to the homepage.

Comment: @Swellar no, that's just a part of the whole html.

Comment: Then figure out what the difference between the successful and unsuccessful responses are. I'm ready to bet on the malformed HTTP cookie header.

Comment: @Dhyey it would be a long post if i post the whole html.anyway i use version  58.0.3029.110

Comment: @deceze is it because I defined two different charset in the html? As you can see, I use ISO-8859-1 and utf-8 charset.

Comment: Would you first care to respond to the `Set-Cookie` header issue hereby raised for the third time?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your Chrome extensions?

Comment: @deceze the Set-Cookie header breaks into two lines because of the editor as the value is long.

Comment: @j08691 yes tried, but unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue.